# Column validation in Sharepoint's list

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to Sharepoint. I want to create a validation rule in column validation to validate the given email address. Here is my code:

```
 =AND(
        ISERROR(FIND(” “, [Email],1)),
        IF(ISERROR(FIND(“@”, [Email],2)),
            FALSE,
                AND(
                    ISERROR(FIND(“@”,[Email], FIND(“@”, [Email],2)+1)),
                    IF(ISERROR(FIND(“.”, [Email], FIND(“@”, [Email],2)+2)),
                    FALSE,
                    FIND(“.”, [Email], FIND(“@”, [Email],2)+2) < LEN([Email])
                )
            )
        )   
    )
```

but the "ISERROR" function does not work and i get a syntax error. My column name is: Email and the type is: Single line of text

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per test, your code works fine on my environment.

Please make sure one thing: please use double quotes with English characters in the validation. It should be `""` instead of `“”`.

```
=AND(
        ISERROR(FIND(" ", [Email],1)),
        IF(ISERROR(FIND("@", [Email],2)),
            FALSE,
                AND(
                    ISERROR(FIND("@",[Email], FIND("@", [Email],2)+1)),
                    IF(ISERROR(FIND(".", [Email], FIND("@", [Email],2)+2)),
                    FALSE,
                    FIND(".", [Email], FIND("@", [Email],2)+2) < LEN([Email])
                )
            )
        )   
    )
```

Comment: I changed to double quotes but still the same problem. I edited my post and added a picture of the error. could you please take a look at it and see if i made some mistakes here?

Comment: ah I found the problem. I had an extra space  after "Email" in column name and the error was because of that.